# I²C with ATTiny85 at 8MHz using TinyWireM library

Tags: i2c, attiny

Hello fellow Arduino enthusiasts, I am trying to make the ATTiny85 talk I²C with a MMA7660 breakout board I have (it's an accelerometer, this is a follow up question to my [previous one](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/mma7660-accelerometer-with-attiny85)).

I would state in advance that the I²C chip works perfectly with Arduino Nano, that I am using the Arduino IDE v1.5.6-r2, using the arduino-tiny core (from [here](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/)) and that until now I had no special issues working at 8MHz.

The official documentation for the **TinyWireM** library (at the [Arduino playground website](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/USIi2c)) states that:

> By default the I2C master library (TinyWireM) is set to run at 1MHz.
>   To run at 8MHz, #defines in USI_TWI_Master.h / .cpp must be changed.

I have made the following changes in **USI_TWI_Master.cpp**:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL // was 1000000UL
```

I have made the following changes in **USI_TWI_Master.h**:

```
#define SYS_CLK   8000.0 // was 1000.0
#define T2_TWI    1.3 // was 5 
#define T4_TWI    0.6 // was 4
```

My guess is that the T2_TWI & the T4_TWI values are wrong. I also tried **T2_TWI 40 and T4_TWI 32** (as stated [here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=81338.0;attach=9917&ei=XgmPU-1XyNvsBq_GgIAG&usg=AFQjCNEr4yeeb28gUYe_4YVmlYgElMjRuA&sig2=TsJqLOXgP5XFU2KdijlJ_Q)), and **T2_TWI 2 & T4_TWI 1** (as stated [here](https://github.com/aboudou/tinywiremcp23008/blob/master/USI_TWI_Master.h)) but no luck. I also tried some other values in between that I thought might make sense but it won't work.

The code I am running is the I²C scanner from [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner) (which as I mentioned works perfectly with the Nano and finds the device), the blow is a modified version for interfacing the TinyWireM library instead of the Wire library:

```
#include <TinyWireM.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(-1,4);

void setup()
{
  TinyWireM.begin();
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("\nI2C Scanner");
}

void loop()
{
  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;
  mySerial.println("Scanning...");
  nDevices = 0;
  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++ ) 
  {
    TinyWireM.beginTransmission(address);
    error = TinyWireM.endTransmission();

    if (error == 0)
    {
      mySerial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address<16) 
        mySerial.print("0");
      mySerial.print(address,HEX);
      mySerial.println("  !");

      nDevices++;
    }
    else if (error==4) 
    {
      mySerial.print("Unknow error at address 0x");
      if (address<16) 
        mySerial.print("0");
      mySerial.println(address,HEX);
    }  
  }
  if (nDevices == 0)
    mySerial.println("No I2C devices found\n");
  else
    mySerial.println("done\n");

  delay(5000);           // wait 5 seconds for next scan
}
```

<strike>As a side note I would say that my logic analyzer was broken recently and I'm sure it would have helped here... Also I am aware of the sound-card hack to be used as logic analyzer, but would prefer to avoid adding more error-prone variables to the system, if possible, for now.</strike>

Here is a picture of probing with Saleae logic analyzer of the two channels. The result of the code above is "No I2C devices found":

[image: Logic sampling of ATTiny I2C channels]

[(Full size picture)](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2s6vyv8.jpg)

Would appreciate the insights of anyone with experience using ATTiny85 at 8Mhz with I²C successfully.

Comment: Did you burn the fuses (upload bootloader) to enable the ATtiny to run at 8MHz?

Comment: @imjosh: yes. thanks for bringing it up. I am always using the same ATTiny for prototyping and from time to time I burn the fuses just to be on the safe side :)

Comment: I took a look at USI_TWI_Master.h, and I don't think T2_TWI and T4_TWI should be changed at all.  Just SYS_CLK   from 1000.0 to 8000.0.  Have you tried it like that?

Comment: Yes. I also tried with the original values. no go.

Comment: Are you using an external crystal or resonator?

Comment: I am using the internal resonator.

Comment: Try using an external crystal or calibrating the internal resonator maybe - https://www.google.com/search?q=calibrate+attiny+internal+resonator

Comment: thanks, but currently I'm looking for a solution that does not require external crystal. Also I could not find any reference on how to calibrate the internal oscillator (and not resonator, according to the spec). In addition I find it hard to believe that SoftwareSerial timing is right if the internal oscillator is not accurate enough.

Comment: Did you manage to successfully run I²C on ATTiny85 without external oscillator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15064/discussion-between-imjosh-and-omer).

Comment: You have the Pull up resisters in place... both of them?

Comment: Yes. Both of them.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I am probably experiencing very similar. My logic analyser says the first byte sent (the slave address) is correct, the rest is nonsense. I tried it on 1Mhz and 8Mhz, correct fuses, fiddling with the T2_TWI/T4_TWI but I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I also checked with logic analyzer and oscilloscope- and I can confirm output is garbage.

Comment: @Omer Looking at [this picture](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2s6vyv8.jpg) from your post, are'nt SDA and SCL signals reversed? SDA looks like clock and SCL looks like data.

Comment: I have the same problem as you with a DHTC3 probe. The I2scanner code does not respond OK to the probe address with an Attiny85 while it works with an Arduino Uno. However, I changed the frequency to 8 Mhz and the 2 timers T2_TWI and T4_TWI. And you, have you solved your problem please?

Answer (score 1):

You really just need to scope the signals, even if it's with a DSO Nano-type scope.

Without downloading the datasheets:

- I would guess your pull-up is probably too small, but possibly too large (scope it)
- Slew rate may be either insufficient or too steep (scope it)
- Be aware that the ATTiny runs at "8MHz", and not 8.00MHz. The timing error can be off enough to cause communication issues at high speeds while working well at lower speeds (scope it, and/or start at default and incrementally increase speed by 0.5MHz until it stops working)
- MMA may not support a typical protocol feature being used, i.e. 'repeated start', burst transfers, etc. (datasheet register/programming section)

Edit: Both the ATTiny and the MMA should have bypass capacitors near the power pins.

Comment: It's kind of easy to miss, but on my last comment to the question I mentioned that I did use logic analyzer and that the results are garbage. It happened with other I2C devices as well, not just MMA. Did you ever got the I2C working with the ATtiny85?

Comment: The Tiny family supports both "I2C" and "SPI", although they are not implemented as separate hardware peripherals. Instead, the Tiny has a generic hardware peripheral called the USI, that can emulate both. 

Of course, both protocols can always be bit-banged for virtually 100% guaranteed communication with anything you want.

Comment: If you feel like it, could you hook up any I2C device up to one and post a capture from your scope?

Comment: I discovered that I have an MMA8451Q on my KL25Z. I will try to run it with the Tiny tomorrow and post back the results.

Comment: The USI part from Atmel documentation is what giving me hope. Unfortunately I never heard of anyone succeeding with it. I'll update my question with a screenshot of the probing.

Comment: uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: I know it's an old post, buy my ATTiny85 talked successfully to the BMP280 sensor via I2C using TinyWireM. And no, the SYS_CLK 8Mhz or 1Mhz doesn't make any difference. It works with any T2 and T4 for me - the 5 and 4 default (faster) or 40 and 32 (just slower). My issue was that I've bit-banged the LCD screen and then initialized via TinyWireM the BMP280 sensor... that mix doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. On adafruit.com there's a product called Trinket which is an ATtiny85 microcontroller board. It can communicate over I2C using their TinyWireM library. Maybe you should  check it out for reference. I hope it helps :)

Comment: The owner of the question has already mentioned they are using the library.